# 3-tier architecture without JavaEE

Tags: java, migration, 3-tier

Question in short:
Is it possible to gradually convert to 3-tier architecture from 2-tier?

Question as it is:

We have a messy kind-of-2-tier application. **Presentation** is in php, **Data** in Oracle, **Business Logic** partially in PLSQL, partially in JavaSE, partially in Php. It is impossible to kill the current software architect, throw everything away and restart with WildFly, for example (unfortunately).

Is it possible to start making layers gradually? 
For example, JavaSE applications with **Business Logic** will stop putting data back to SQL, but what is the right way for Php to get data from JavaSE?

I've read about SOAP a little, but if website on Php will start getting/sending all data through it, it will be extremely cumbersome (as I see it)

Comment: "It is impossible to kill the current software architect"?:)

Comment: Lets get one thing out of the way: the historic choices are going to make this process as cumbersome and costly as it can be, there is no easy way out. You'll  have to mentally accept that, and then redesign and **rebuild** the JavaSE stuff into a RESTful webservice. My crystal ball tells me the existing code is not written to be reusable in any way.

Comment: long answer, yes it is possible, my suggestion will be first to tidy up, and decide to use one language for business layer, my short answer will be run, if current architect is still working on that project, as well as team of people who let this design happened, i think you will be much safer somewhere else

Comment: So, after all, SOAP is my best option. Will learn more about it. Thank you for your opinions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just my opinion:
I will go for rewriting your backend in Java (SE or even EE) completely. You can also have advantages for your data-layer access using ORM's like Hibernate. The best way to work im my opinion is to use RESTful webservices or SOAP. There are many libraries for PHP (including the SOAP extension) so you don't have to worry about using SOAP with PHP.
Give a read to: 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Many PHP frameworks support SOAP and will give a big help when refactoring your frontend.

So in few words. Your frontend (php) will call Java backend businnes layer that will make all the businnes logic (you may port your PLSQL logic here) and than finally dialogate with your Data layer.